# Disable inkwell click feature in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there a way to disable the [`InkWell`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InkWell-class.html) click feature?
(I don't want to make it conditional with if and else in [`onTap`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InkResponse/onTap.html), I want it not to be clickable at all).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do not pass the `onTap` function it will be non-clickable,Try this:

```
InkWell(
   child: Text('click'),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply don't give it an `onTap`. Leave it out

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
InkWell(
  child: write your code here,
)
```